# Firebase orderByChild without repeated data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to sort and display firebase data however I'm stuck. My database looks like this :

[image]

I need to sort the data by `nr_of_matches` and I can do that by querying like this :

```
      const ref = firebase.database().ref('Matches/'+db_name).orderByChild('nr_of_matches')

      ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      const matches = childSnapshot.val().matches
      const nr_of_matches = childSnapshot.val().nr_of_matches
      const the_matched = childSnapshot.val().the_matched
      console.log("matches : "+matches)

    });
    });
```

However, I retrieve repeated data doing it like this. 
To not get repeated data I can do it like this:

```
      const ref = firebase.database().ref('Matches/'+db_name+"/"+child.key).orderByChild('nr_of_matches')

      ref.on('value', function (snapshot) {
      const matches = snapshot.val().matches
      const nr_of_matches = snapshot.val().nr_of_matches
      const the_matched = snapshot.val().the_matched
      console.log("matches : "+matches)

    });
```

but then it's not sorted anymore. Any idea how do sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to retrieve repeated data, then you can use a `query`:

```
      const ref = firebase.database().ref('Matches/'+db_name+"/").orderByChild('nr_of_matches').equalto(2);

      ref.on('value', function (snapshot) {
      const matches = snapshot.val().matches
      const nr_of_matches = snapshot.val().nr_of_matches
      const the_matched = snapshot.val().the_matched
      console.log("matches : "+matches)

    });
```